# How do i solve a system of 5 fourth degree polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

So, I have to model the sun's density as a function of R, solar radii. I was tasked with doing so from a graph in a book, so i collected some data:
$$(y;x)=(\rho;R)$$
$A(150;0) \space B(1;0,5)\space C(0,001;0,75)\space D(0;1)\space E(0,00001;0,99)$

From Nasa's own approximation of this was also a fourth-degree polynomial equation.

I've got the following equations:
$$150=e$$
$$1=a\cdot(0,5)^4+b\cdot(0,5)^3 +c\cdot(0,5)^2 +d\cdot(0,5)+e $$
$$0,001=a\cdot(0,75)^4+b\cdot(0,75)^3 +c\cdot(0,75)^2 +d\cdot(0,75)+e $$
$$0=a\cdot(1)^4+b\cdot(1)^3 +c\cdot(1)^2 +d\cdot(1)+e $$
$$0,00001=a\cdot(0,99)^4+b\cdot(0,99)^3 +c\cdot(0,99)^2 +d\cdot(0,99)+e $$

Comment: from where Comes this System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite as a linear system $Ax =b$ where

$$x = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\end{bmatrix}\qquad b = \begin{bmatrix}150\\ 1\\0.001\\0\\0.00001\end{bmatrix}$$

And $A$ is the $5\times 5$ matrix containing the respective coefficients. Then use your favourite solver to get a numerical solution (Matlab, Wolfram alpha, Ti-83 calculator, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a system of linear equations that you can solve simultaneously.

From the fourth equation, $a=-150-b-c-d$. Substitute this into the second, third and fifth equations. You now have a system of three linear equations in three unknowns ($b,c,d$). Rearrange one of these three equations to make, say, $b$ the subject. Now substitute this expression for $b$ into the other two equations. You now have two simultaneous equations in $c$ and $d$. Solve these two equations for $c$ and $d$. To find $b$, substitute back into your expression for $b$, and then back into your expression for $a$ to find $a$.

If you know about matrices, you could also write this system of equations in the form $Ax=v$ where $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix, $x=(a,b,c,d,e)^T$ and $v=(150,1,0.001,0,0.0001)$. Then, provided $A$ is invertible, $x=A^{-1}v$.